# Identify user/pc without authentication in ASP.NET Core

Tags: session, asp.net-core, session-cookies, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to achieve the following:
Have an unauthenticated user navigate to a web page, where a SignalR (core) client will connect to a hub (say Notifications hub).
Have the user perform an action and, when the operation is completed on the server, use SignalR to notify him of the completion.
The problem: when a user is logged, I find his SignalR connectionId by a connectionId-username map that is saved in memory. Then I do:

```
hub.SendConnectionAsync(connectionId, "Message", data);
```

If the user is not authenticated, I came up with using SessionId, and the map I save in memory is something that gives me a ConnectionId given a SessionId. The code snippet I use on the HubLifetimeManager is something like:

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync(HubConnectionContext connection)
    {
        await _wrappedHubLifetimeManager.OnConnectedAsync(connection);
        _connections.Add(connection);
        string userId;
        if (connection.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            userId = connection.User.Identity.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            var httpContext = connection.GetHttpContext();
            if (httpContext == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("HttpContext can't be null in a SignalR Hub!!");
            }
            var sessionId = httpContext.Session.Id;
            userId = $"{Constants.AnonymousUserIdentifierPrefix}{sessionId}";
        }
        await _userTracker.AddUser(connection, new UserDetails(connection.ConnectionId, userId));
    }
```

Problem: if my page is opened in an iframe, httpContext.Session.Id is the empty string, it looks like the cookies of my page opened in the iframe (among which is the Session cookie), are not added to the http requests performed by the javascript code executed inside the iframe...

More generally, how do you identify a user if he's not authenticated? Is there anything in the HttpRequest that you can use as a unique id, like machine name or ip?

Comment: No. There's very little information about the client in the request headers, and then only if the client *chooses* to even send those headers, and then if the client is actually *honest* about those headers (the client can send whatever it likes). The only way to identity a user/device is: 1) authentication and 2) a cookie. However, in the latter, again, the client can choose not to send a cookie, disable cookies, etc. In other words, if you need to ensure you're working with a particular user, the only fool-proof way is authentication.

Comment: I'm still investigating but it seems the part about cookies not being usable in iframes isn't true. Therefore I'm using the Session Id to identify the client. Sure it's not an ideal approach but I can't figure out how to do it otherwise.

Comment: Auth. Use auth. You can handle it in a very light weight way. It doesn't mean, for example, that you have to go through a whole sign up process or something. In it's most simplistic form, it can simply be assigning a token and making all future requests send that token back.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify an anonymous user you could use a custom http header generated on frontend. It can be accessed with `IHttpContextAccessor` in combination with custom `IUserIdProvider`:

```cs
 public class CustomUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider  
 {  
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;  
  
    public CustomUserIdProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)  
    {  
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;  
    }  
  
    public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)  
    {  
        if (connection.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return connection.User.Identity.Name;
        }

        var username = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Headers["username"];
        if (username.HasValue && !StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(username.Value))
        {
            return username.Value;
        }

        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 
    }  
 }
```

Remember that in `.NET Core` you need to explicitly add `IHttpContextAccessor` to the DI container:

```cs
  services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
  services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, CustomUserIdProvider>();
  services.AddSignalR();
```

Then you can use the generated identifier in hub method like this:

```cs
 public override async Task OnConnectedAsync(HubConnectionContext connection)
 {
    await _wrappedHubLifetimeManager.OnConnectedAsync(connection);
    _connections.Add(connection);
    string userId = connection.UserIdentifier;
    await _userTracker.AddUser(connection, new UserDetails(connection.ConnectionId, userId));
 }
```

Source: https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2020/march/custom-signalr-hub-authorization-in-aspnet-core/